# FAB relative to bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I am using Bottom Sheet from support library 23.4.0. And I want to add a FAB just above the bottom sheet.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
 <AppBarLayout/>
     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_main">
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/map_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/map_bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

This results in correct margin when bottom sheet is visibility=gone as seen here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBgKq.png). But when bottom sheet is expanded the margin is gone as seen in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NYg9.png)

Comment: You're missing the 'expected behaviour' screenshot, so we can understand what exactly you want

Comment: I cannot add another image due to my low reputation. I expected to have that wide margin even if the bottom sheet is expanded.

Comment: Link the image here in the comments, I don't get you

Comment: Expected result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BNjvp.png

Comment: I add a FAB to my  Bottom Sheet just like you. I add the app:layout_anchor and app:layout_anchorGravity to my FAB, But the FAB doesn't move.How does your anchor works, do I miss sth?

Comment: Check https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4